# How can I replace a especific line with fstream?

Tags: c++, replace, fstream

I have this:

```
std::fstream fullscreenData("variables/fullscreenData.txt", std::ios::in | std::ios::out);

            while (std::getline(fullscreenData, *streamString)) {
            *streamString = static_cast<std::string>("Fullscreen: false");
                if (*streamString == static_cast<std::string>("Fullscreen: false")) {

                    fullscreenData << "Fullscreen: true\n";
                }
            }
            fullscreenData.close();
```

I was testing adn I can use the "while" and the "if" to read from the txt, and the  "fullscreenData <<" to write in the txt.
But if I use it together it doesn't work, nothing is writed in the txt.

Someone knows what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Oh god. Why are you casting to `std::string`?!

Comment: And why is streamString a pointer to std::string?

Comment: You can't replace lines in a file. You can only overwrite some bytes, so you can only replace the bytes of one line with exactly the same count of other bytes.

Comment: I'm casting because it takes the text as a char and it doesn't work, and streamstring is a normal string variable.

Comment: Also overwrite is what I want to do.

Comment: You can't convert a single character to a string data type by using a cast.

Comment: Then that may be the problem, how can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an issue with your data types.

You may want to try something like this:

```
std::streampos  position_line_begin(0);
std::string     text;
while (std::getline(fullScreenData, text))
{
  if (text == "Fullscreen: false")
  {
     fullScreenData.seekp(position_line_begin);
     fullScreenData << "Fullscreen: true \n";
     break;
  }
  position_line_begin = fullScreenData.tellg();
}
```

There are better methods, but this demonstrates the algorithm.

Comment: It would be safer to output to a separate file, and then replace the original file only if a change is detected.